# Definitions of Picard schemes and Picard stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to S$ be a morphism of schemes. The Picard functor $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}_{X/S}$ is defined to be the associated sheaf of the absolute Picard functor $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}_X(T) = \mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}(X_T)$ in the fppf topology (or $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}(X_T) / \mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}(T)$). However, in the definition of Picard stack $\mathop{\mathscr{Pic}}_{X/S}$, see [0372](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0372), it neither takes the stackification nor take the quotient, and the presheaf associated to $\mathop{\mathscr{Pic}}_{X/S}$ is the absolute Picard functor $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}_X$, so I do not understand why $\mathop{\mathscr{Pic}}_{X/S}$ is a stack.

And under certain conditions, $\mathop{\mathscr{Pic}}_{X/S}$ is represented by an algebraic stack, see [0D04](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D04), and $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}_{X/S}$ is represented by a scheme, see section 9.4 of *FGA explained*. I wonder whether the algebraic stack is the same as the scheme.

Comment: The map $\mathscr Pic \to \mathbf{Pic}$ is a $\mathbf G_m$-gerbe (at least if $f_* \mathcal O_X = \mathcal O_S$ holds universally), roughly because $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathscr L) \cong \mathbf G_m$ for any $\mathscr L \in \mathscr Pic_{X/S}(T)$. (This is not quite enough to conclude, because gerbes are not just defined pointwise.)